# How can I update values in multiple excel spreadsheets in a SharePoint 2016 document library?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, excel

We have a document library containing 44 excel spreadsheets.  Within each spreadsheet there is a "Employee Name" column.

Is it possible to update a value (ex. Change "Employee Name" column value from Joe to ED) in all excel spreadsheets without opening each spreadsheet and manually updating the value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

The short answer is NO.

We could not update the column in excel without manually open all excel spreadsheets.

Comment: Thanks you for response.  

I'm looking for a way to update content in a column in an excel spreadsheet in the document library.  For example, I need to update a column in the "Sample" excel spreadsheet listed above. 

It looks like the quick edit only updates the form.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question, I have updated my reply.

Answer (score 0):

se me ocurre si la información en el Excel está es formato tabla, por medio de un flujo de Power automate podrías cambiar esa información